# PHP wont receive POST data from AJAX using FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, form-data

I am trying to pass some basic data using JavaScript and PHP.

The PHP is not receiving any data.

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("action", "save-game");
formData.append("title", title);
formData.append("players", players);
formData.append("noTables", noTables);
formData.append("maxPPT", maxPPT);
formData.append("rounds", roundChart);

$.ajax({
    url: "/static/apps/games.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response){
        if (response.success) {
            alert("Saved Game Setup");
        } else {
            alert("Failed to save game setup, "+response.reason);
            console.log(response.reason);
        }
    }
})
```

And I have stripped the PHP down to the bare minimum but it is still not receiving the data

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$action = $_POST["action"];

echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => false,
    'reason' => $action,
));
```

The `$action` variable in PHP is returning `null`

Comment: It's likely in a console error on your javascript side. Go look :)

Comment: Whether PHP understands such a request, stands and falls with the Content-Type header. You for some reason decided to instruct jQuery to not send one at all, so of course this fails.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Also checking the console and network tab are a good start to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have always used contentType: false in all my ajax calls and they work. I have tried using contentType: 'application/json' but it still returns null

Comment: `application/json` is not the correct content type to send standard POST data either. Just leave this setting out completely ...

Comment: jquery version is 3.2.1. nothing unorthodox is coming up in the console. In the network tab it is saying that my request method is GET although I have set as POST but $action = $_GET['action'] is also not working

Comment: leaving contentType out does nothing either

Comment: Have you tried `method` instead of `type` then? Docs say the latter is an alias for the former, but maybe it was removed in later versions.

Comment: no luck @CBroe. still telling me the request method is GET

Comment: your `content-type: multipart/form-data` not `json`, try edit in php or check network tab

Comment: _"still telling me the request method is GET"_ - are you sure you're looking at the right section of code to begin with ...? That GET request is the only one showing in network panel ... not maybe a POST directly before it, that gets a redirect response or something like that?

Comment: no luck with multipart/formdata. it is the only ajax call on the page @CBroe

Comment: Do you have this online anywhere we could take a look?

Comment: there was an issue with the .htaccess file which was preventing the page from sending POST.

Answer (score 0):

try to build data  like here

```js
var buildData = function( _action, _title, _players, _noTables, _maxPPT, _rounds){
  var data = {};
  data.action = _action;
  data.title = _title;
  data.players = _players;
  data.noTables = _noTables;
  data.maxPPT = _maxPPT;
  data.rounds = _rounds;

  return JSON.stringify(data);
}

var _json = buildData("save-game", title, players, noTables, maxPPT, roundChart);
```